# @ExceptionHandler not working in a Service class

Tags: spring-boot, exception, exceptionhandler

The below is a service class

```
@Service
class Test {

    public Object findEmployees1(String id, String dbId) {
        return employeeRepo.findByDatabaseIdAndIdentifier(dbId, id);

    }
    
        public Object findEmployees2(String name, String dbId) {
        Object records = employeeRepo.findByNameAndDatabaseId(name, dbId);

    }
    
    
        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public void internalErrorExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Log the exception here");
        throw new InternalErrorException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I want if any exception(eg some SQLException) comes in any of the method in the class test , it gets caught by the `@ExceptionHandler` and is logged there and re thrown

I cannot use `@ExceptionHandler` with `@ControllerAdvice` as I don't have any class with @Controller annotation on it . I am writing just a common module to get data from the database.

When I execute the code , the log under `@ExceptionHandler` is not printed as it never gets called.
The requirement is to log and rethrow a common exception if any exception comes in any of the service class methods without having individual try catch statements in each method.

Comment: `@ExceptionHandler` is a web only annotation and won't work otherwise.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Is there any other way to achieve the same thing in Service class ?

Comment: Use AOP for that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use spring aop to handle such exceptions. Instead of duplicating I will link to the existing question I have tried to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864533/not-throwing-exception-from-a-services-methods).

The other way is, if you are using ByteBuddy, you can use following annotation on the method which is expected to throw exception.

```
@Advice.OnMethodExit(onThrowable = RuntimeException.class)
```